# Binary stream '226' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader - C#

Tags: c#, encryption, serialization, binaryformatter

I've got a typical 'Binary stream 'x' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader', but all of the questions I've looked at online don't seem to solve my specific situation.

**Issue details**

The part of the program in question in it's most basic terms writes class data to a binary file. This works flawlessly 99.9% of the time, but we have recently discovered an obscure way to get the data to corrupt.

So the class which gets serialized is a public class called *'RecordEntry'* marked with the `[Serializable]` attribute. The class inherits from an interface. *'RecordEntry'* contains a bunch of variables with information, but the one that causes us an issue is an array of a class called *'EntryField'*. This is an extremely simple class which holds 3 strings and is also marked as `[Serializable]`.

If the array of *'EntryField'* classes (lets call it *'EntryFieldArray'*), has a length of 4, and the first string in each *'EntryField'* has a length of 13, and the third string in each has a length of 1, then when trying to deserialize, I get the error in the title. There are probably a few more obscure ways to reproduce the same crash, but that's the one I've found right now.

**Serialization code**

Firstly, the *'RecordEntry'* class is converted to bytes:

```
public static byte[] ToBytes(this object obj)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

That byte array is then added to the file as a block of data.

For reading the encrypted file back, firstly the bytes are read back in the defined blocks, and then decrypted using the following:

```
internal static T ObjectFromBytes<T>(this byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Here's the important part of the stack-trace to track the error:

```js
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : Binary stream '226' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at <ProjectName>.<ProjectFile>.ObjectFromBytes[T](Byte[] bytes)
```

I can't seem to trace the issue back, and some developers I've contacted about this said it could be an issue with the Microsoft serialization code. Any ideas on what could cause an issue like this?

Comment: The code seems to be correct. Are you serializing and deserializing between different programs? `BinarySerializer` is very picky about changes to the structure of the objects, and perhaps the same code compiled with different versions of .NET could generate incompatible serialized objects

Comment: @xanatos The 'ObjectFromBytes' and 'ToBytes', and also the writing to the file itself is handled in a custom library, which is compiled as a DLL, then added to our main project. This main project then feeds the raw data (such as strings and integers) into the custom library to be fed into the data structures discussed above, and then the library does the encryption/decryption. Looking at the library and the main project, they appear to target the same version of .NET.

Comment: It might be worth noting that our main project has a Platform target of x86, and the class library has a target of 'Any CPU' - But I don't think that would matter.

Answer (score 0):

You write of encryption... Perhaps there is some problem with how the encryption is done... The best thing you can do is add some checks to your serialized data.

```
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function
public static uint JenkinsOneAtATimeHash(byte[] key, int start, int count)
{
    int i = start;
    int end = start + count;
    uint hash = 0;
    while (i != end)
    {
        hash += key[i++];
        hash += hash << 10;
        hash ^= hash >> 6;
    }
    hash += hash << 3;
    hash ^= hash >> 11;
    hash += hash << 15;
    return hash;
}

public static byte[] ToBytes(this object obj)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        // We will prepend the length of the serialized object, we leave some space
        stream.Position += sizeof(int);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);

        // We append a Jenkins hash of the serialized object
        uint hash = JenkinsOneAtATimeHash(stream.GetBuffer(), 4, (int)stream.Length - sizeof(int));

        byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(hash);
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        // We prepend the length of the serialized object (max 2gb)
        buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)stream.Length - sizeof(int) - sizeof(int));
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}

internal static T ObjectFromBytes<T>(this byte[] bytes)
{
    if (bytes.Length < sizeof(int) + sizeof(int))
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Serialized length: {0} < {1}", bytes.Length, sizeof(int) + sizeof(int)));
    }

    int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

    if (length != bytes.Length - sizeof(int) - sizeof(int))
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Serialized length should be {0}, is {1} (+ sizeof(int) * 2)", length, bytes.Length - sizeof(int) - sizeof(int)));
    }

    uint hash = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, bytes.Length - 4);

    uint hash2 = JenkinsOneAtATimeHash(bytes, sizeof(int), bytes.Length - sizeof(int) - sizeof(int));

    if (hash != hash2)
    {
        throw new Exception("Wrong hash!");
    }

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes, sizeof(int), bytes.Length - sizeof(int) - sizeof(int)))
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

I've changed the serialization and deserialization methods. Now I prepend the length of the object and append a [simple hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function). It isn't a very strong hash, but it should be enough to detect changes to the data. Upon deserialization I make some checks on the length of the stream and on the hash.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll give this a go and post back here.